# SQlite C warnings

Tags: c, sqlite, compiler-warnings

I am using the sqlite3.c library.
It compiles with 140 something conversion warnings.
What's wrong with my set-up?

Thanks.

```
sqlite3.c
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11311) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11312) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11313) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11316) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11430) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11431) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11434) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11435) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11436) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11437) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11452) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11454) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11499) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11505) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11547) : warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11607) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11633) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11720) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11722) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11724) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11726) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11730) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11736) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11738) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11742) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11781) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'sqlite3_int64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11950) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'u64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11981) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(11984) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(12007) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'char', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(12607) : warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(16030) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(17184) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite_uint64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(17512) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(19310) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u64' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(19313) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u64' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(19320) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u64' to 'u8', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25669) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25670) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25702) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25703) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25735) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(25736) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'LONG', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(28785) : warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29505) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29511) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29734) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29747) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29871) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(29887) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(30081) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(30360) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(30367) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'Pgno', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(30370) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(30665) : warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(31713) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(31771) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(31978) : warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(33807) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(33809) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(34527) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u16' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(34623) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(35382) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u16' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(35884) : warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(36557) : warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(36674) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(36679) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(36880) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(36887) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37265) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37267) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37272) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37273) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37343) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37557) : warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37695) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37891) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37962) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(37964) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(38070) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u16' to 'u8', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(38150) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u16' to 'u8', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(39686) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(40231) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(40541) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'Pgno', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(40590) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'sqlite3_int64' to 'Pgno', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(40671) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'i64' to 'Pgno', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41144) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41152) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41153) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41493) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41688) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'const i64' to 'double', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(41693) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'const i64' to 'double', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(42031) : warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(43995) : warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44011) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44118) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u64' to 'u8', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44132) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44287) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44382) : warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44444) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44489) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(44827) : warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(45006) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'i64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(45036) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'u64', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(46720) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(46735) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(47061) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(47071) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(47168) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'double', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(47961) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(47982) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48020) : warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48038) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48055) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48235) : warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48258) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'u64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48270) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'u64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48275) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48493) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48497) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u8', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(48633) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(49420) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(49564) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'u32', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(49567) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(50183) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(50189) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(50635) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(50636) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(62675) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(62711) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(63239) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(63512) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(63513) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(63514) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'i64' to 'int', possible loss of data
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(65536) : warning C4049: compiler limit : terminating line number emission
        Compiler limit for line number is 65535
c:\Projects\Lib\sqlite3.c(77234) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'u16' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SQLite web site:

> Some people say that we should
>   eliminate all warnings because benign
>   warnings mask real warnings that might
>   arise in future changes. This is true
>   enough. But in reply, the developers
>   observe that all warnings have already
>   been fixed in the compilers used for
>   SQLite development (various versions
>   of GCC). Compiler warnings only arise
>   from compilers that the developers do
>   not have access to.

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q17

Comment: They don't have access Visual Studio?!?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2005 or 2008, it's easy to configure the compiler warning level just on sqlite.c.  That way, you can use a nice verbose /w4 on all the code that you write and a /w1 on sqlite3.c so you don't get these warnings.  Right-click sqlite.c in the solution explorer, click on Properties, drill down to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General, and select /W1 or /W0 from the Warning Level drop-down.

I haven't tried this approach in other versions of VS or VC++.  It would be great if you mentioned your specific compiler/IDE.

Comment: +1: This is a very nice tip. I don't understand why no-one else voted this up.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not your setup. SQLite is written with lots of warnings. They haven't been fixed for years. Not much to do but ignore the warnings or contribute back patches